# uninitialized local variable used in C language

Tags: c

so i have been at this for a bit and i am a little stumped i am getting "uninitialized local variable gallons used". in my take_Input function on conversion(gallons);

i am aware that that means that the value for gallons is not being recognized.

why is the gallons to liters function not placing a value for gallons so that the conversion function has that value. any help appreciated thanks...

code:

```
double take_Input(void) 
{
    double a, b, c, d;
    double gallons;

    printf("please enter how many liters of A: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("please enter how many gallons of B: ");
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    printf("please enter how many liters of C: ");
    scanf("%lf", &c);
    printf("please enter how many gallons of D: ");
    scanf("%lf", &d);

    gallons_To_Liters(a,b,c,d);

    conversions(gallons);
    return(0);
}

double gallons_To_Liters(double a, double b, double c,double d) 
{ 
    double gallons, liters;

    liters = a + c;
    gallons = b + d;
    gallons = (liters * 3.79) + gallons;
    return(0);
}

double conversions(double gallons) 
{
    double totalGallons = gallons;
    double quarts = totalGallons * 4;
    double pints = totalGallons * 8;
    double cups = totalGallons * 16;
    double fluid_ounces = totalGallons * 128;
    double tablespoons = totalGallons * 256;
    double teaspoons = totalGallons * 768;
    // output statements.
    printf("the amount of gallons is: %.2f \n", totalGallons);
    printf("the amount of quarts is: %.2f \n", quarts);
    printf("the amount of pints is: %.2f \n", pints);
    printf("the amount of cups is: %.2f \n", cups);
    printf("the amount of fluid ounces is: %.2f \n", fluid_ounces);
    printf("the amount of tablespoons is: %.2f \n", tablespoons);
    printf("the amount of teaspoons is: %.2f \n", teaspoons);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the concept of *scope*.

Comment: @EOF maybe the local is US gallons..

Comment: Who needs a 10-gallon hat when you have a 2-gallon app?

Comment: Why create a method that returns an double (gallons_To_Liters) when it always returns zero, and when you never assign its value to anything?(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gallons_To_Liters` function sets the local variable `gallons`, but does nothing with it.  You need to return this value from the function.

Then in the calling function, you need to assign the return value of `gallons_To_Liters` to the `gallons` variable in that function.

```
double take_Input(void) 
{
    ....
    gallons = gallons_To_Liters(a,b,c,d);
    ....
}

double gallons_To_Liters(double a, double b, double c,double d) 
{ 
    double gallons, liters;

    liters = a + c;
    gallons = b + d;
    gallons = (liters * 3.79) + gallons;
    return gallons;
}
```

You need to keep in mind that variables in different functions are distinct from each other, even if their names are the same.

Also, for the `take_Input` and `conversion` functions, their return values are not used for anything, so change the functions to have a return type of `void` and remove the `return` statements from those functions.

Comment: appreciate the help. this worked and i am in only my second real semester of programming and taking java and C at the same time so as a beginner i am bound to run into some issues.